# Excel - Get equation for a curve connecting three points

Tags: excel, vba

I have three points (Year, growth) and I would like to find an equation connecting them in Excel:

```
Point 1: (2016, 3033%)
Point 2: (2017, 397%)
Point 3: (2023, 20%)
```

Is there a way to do it on Excel. I tried power 4 quadratic equation using `Linest(Range1, Range2^{1,2,3,4})` but I have an area of growth below zero. Not a curve that drops sharply between 2016 and 2017 before stabilizing between 2017 and 2023. Growth cannot be negative on this case. 
I would like to build equations so that if user change the growth in 2023 for example it will automatically modify the function and so 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 and 2023 can be found.
Anybody knows how to do on Excel please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to fit your table to an exponential function that has a negative coefficient for the variable of the exponent, i.e. y = A exp(-bx)

You can use the LINEST() function in excel to do that if you linearize the equation:
lny = lnA + bx

A scatterplot with a linear trendline will also give you the coefficient.
Take a look at https://www.engineerexcel.com/nonlinear-curve-fitting-in-excel/

Comment: thank you. I tried this : =LINEST(y_values,ln(x_values),TRUE,FALSE) but get negative data. How would you do precisely in the two cells please ? Say 2016 is in A2.

Comment: Hi. The negative data is the gradient or b in the equation. You can select 2 cells say A2 and B2, then paste the function "LINEST(y_values,ln(x_xalues),TRUE,FALSE) in the formula bar then press ctrl+shift+enter. 'b' will be in A2 and the intercept lnA in B2.